Is it possible to use the attribute xml:lang in a xsd?
Now I am trying to make a xsd file based on xml just as below (the xml almost not editable):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<root> 
    <myname> 
        <description> 
            <mystring xml:lang="en"></mystring> 
            <mystring xml:lang="fr"></mystring> 
        </description> 
    </myname> 
</root>

There is no problem to generate a test.xsd using a xml edit tool,  but when bind the xml with the xsd add namespace like this
<root xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
</root>

It not works, show error Attribute 'xml:lang' is not allowed to appear in element 'mystring'

Seems the attribute xml:lang is integrated in xml？ How can i  use it im my custom element attribute?
I am totally new with xml,  greatly appreciate it if anybody could offer some advice...
to enbale the attibute xml:lang in my xml and xsd file

While xml:lang has a meaning defined (but not enforced!) by the XML specifications, it isn't magically valid everywhere - it's only allowed on an element if the schema permits it. And to permit it, your schema needs to declare it as an allowed attribute, which means it will need to import the schema for the XML namespace.

You need to import the schema https://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd. And see https://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd#ann_3 how to use the imported attribute declaration(s) or declaration group(s).
Also keep in mind that for W3C resources like schemas and DTD it is better to use a local copy, often easily done with a catalog that maps W3C URIs to local file system URIs.

Yes you can use the xml:lang attribute in XSD but you can't directly enforce language constraints with it. The xml:lang attribute is used to specify the language of the content in XML documents, but XML Schema itself does not validate the value of this attribute.
